No information for converting svg format files to pdf6
I am using LyX 2.4.1 installed on Fedora 40. I am trying to create a PDF from a document and getting this:
No information for converting svg format files to pdf6.
Define a converter in the preferences.
magick: unable to read image data `/tmp/lyx_tmpdir.glGKNcHFCHSq/lyx_tmpbuf0/91_home_myself_Desktop_lyx_thesis_chapters_blah.svg' @ error/svg.c/RenderRSVGImage/456.
/usr/share/lyx/scripts/convertDefault.py ERROR
Execution of "magick" failed.
Systemcall.cpp (306): Systemcall: 'python3 -tt "/usr/share/lyx/scripts/convertDefault.py" svg "/tmp/lyx_tmpdir.glGKNcHFCHSq/lyx_tmpbuf0/91_home_myself_Desktop_lyx_thesis_chapters_blah.svg" pdf "/tmp/lyx_tmpdir.glGKNcHFCHSq/lyx_tmpbuf0/91_home_myself_Desktop_lyx_thesis_chapters_blah.pdf"' finished with exit code 1

How can I fix it? The image was drawn using Inkscape.
Additional info: I see the python script is doing stuff with ImageMagick, which is already installed:
$ sudo dnf install ImageMagick
Last metadata expiration check: 0:39:07 ago on Sun 11 Aug 2024 11:08:30 AM CEST.
Package ImageMagick-1:7.1.1.33-1.fc40.x86_64 is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!


I would suggest installing rsvg-convert, or inkscape. One of those is better but I forget which. The reason is you want vector conversion. AFter installing, then reconfigure LyX. Then exit. Then start LyX and see if it works.
